# Arrange a matrix by rownames

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with 40 rows. It looks like this :

```
Sample_10.rare       0       0
Sample_11.rare       0      42
Sample_12.rare       0       0
Sample_13.rare     762     550
Sample_14.rare     847     508
Sample_15.rare    1143     593
Sample_16.rare    5630    5291
Sample_17.rare    4064    3683
Sample_18.rare    5969    4318
Sample_19.rare      42     212
Sample_1.rare     5037    3598
Sample_20.rare     127     381
Sample_21.rare     127       0
Sample_22.rare     339     254
Sample_23.rare       0      85
Sample_24.rare       0       0
Sample_25.rare      42      42
Sample_26.rare     339     339
Sample_27.rare    5376    4741
Sample_28.rare   11006    8678
Sample_29.rare     339     296
Sample_2.rare     6815    5164
Sample_30.rare     212     466
```

I would like to rearrange the order of the rows. From the row `Sample_1.rare` to the row `Sample_40.rare` , in the good order. Is there a solution?

Comment: `mat[gtools::mixedorder(rownames(mat)), ]`

Comment: Without using any packages remove all non-digits from the rownames, convert them to numeric, generate the permutation `o` that would sort the rows and apply it: `o <- order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", rownames(m)))); m[o, ]`

Comment: without using any package we can use matrix[order(rownames(mat)),]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mixedorder` from `gtools` package,i.e.

```
m2[gtools::mixedorder(rownames(m2)),]
```

which gives,

> ```
>                   V2   V3
> Sample_1.rare   5037 3598
> Sample_2.rare   6815 5164
> Sample_10.rare     0    0
> Sample_11.rare     0   42
> Sample_12.rare     0    0
> Sample_13.rare   762  550
> Sample_14.rare   847  508
> Sample_15.rare  1143  593
> Sample_16.rare  5630 5291
> Sample_17.rare  4064 3683
> Sample_18.rare  5969 4318
> Sample_19.rare    42  212
> Sample_20.rare   127  381
> Sample_21.rare   127    0
> Sample_22.rare   339  254
> Sample_23.rare     0   85
> Sample_24.rare     0    0
> Sample_25.rare    42   42
> Sample_26.rare   339  339
> Sample_27.rare  5376 4741
> Sample_28.rare 11006 8678
> Sample_29.rare   339  296
> Sample_30.rare   212  466
> ```

**DATA**

```
dput(m2)
structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 762L, 847L, 1143L, 5630L, 4064L, 5969L, 
42L, 5037L, 127L, 127L, 339L, 0L, 0L, 42L, 339L, 5376L, 11006L, 
339L, 6815L, 212L, 0L, 42L, 0L, 550L, 508L, 593L, 5291L, 3683L, 
4318L, 212L, 3598L, 381L, 0L, 254L, 85L, 0L, 42L, 339L, 4741L, 
8678L, 296L, 5164L, 466L), .Dim = c(23L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Sample_10.rare", "Sample_11.rare", "Sample_12.rare", "Sample_13.rare", 
    "Sample_14.rare", "Sample_15.rare", "Sample_16.rare", "Sample_17.rare", 
    "Sample_18.rare", "Sample_19.rare", "Sample_1.rare", "Sample_20.rare", 
    "Sample_21.rare", "Sample_22.rare", "Sample_23.rare", "Sample_24.rare", 
    "Sample_25.rare", "Sample_26.rare", "Sample_27.rare", "Sample_28.rare", 
    "Sample_29.rare", "Sample_2.rare", "Sample_30.rare"), c("V2", 
    "V3")))
```